# NServiceBus Sagas and REST API Integration best-practices

Tags: api, architecture, nservicebus

What is the most sensible approach to integrate/interact NServiceBus Sagas with REST APIs?

The scenario is as follows,

- We have a load balanced REST API. Depending on the load we can add more nodes.
- REST API is a wrapper around a DomainServices API. This means the API can be consumed directly.
- We would like to use Sagas for workflow and implement NServiceBus Distributor to scale-out.

Question is, if we use the REST API from Sagas, the actual processing happens in the API farm. This in a way defeats the purpose of implementing distributor pattern.

On the other hand, using DomainServives API directly from Sagas, allows processing locally within worker nodes. With this approach we will have to maintain API assemblies in multiple locations but the throughput could be higher.

I am trying to understand the best approach. Personally, I’d prefer to consume the API (if readily available) but this could introduce chattiness to the system and could take longer to complete as compared to to in-process.

A typical sequence could be similar to publishing an online advertisement,

- Advertiser submits a new advertisement request via a web application.
- Web application invokes the relevant API endpoint and sends a command
  message.
- Command message initiates a new publish advertisement Saga
  instance.
- Saga sends a command to validate caller permissions (in
  process/out of process API call)
- Saga sends a command to validate the
  advertisement data (in process/out of process API call)
- Saga sends a
  command to the fraud service (third party service)
- Once the content and fraud verifications are successful,
- Saga sends a command to the billing system.
- Saga invokes an API call to save add details. (in
  process/out of process API call)

And this goes on until the advertisement is expired, there are a number of retry and failure condition paths.

Comment: What actual problem is the saga supposed to address during the scale out process?

Comment: Throughput, the actual Saga is Short-running process, it runs comparatively quickly, for not more than a few seconds, it will likely have a single burst. But the number of requests is high, so having a distributor in place helps scaling out. 

Alternatively as I’ve mentioned, having a load balanced API also does the same thing, because the actual work takes place in API nodes worker nodes does the coordination.

Comment: So just so I understand this, you are trying to use a saga to call a load balanced web service? On top of that you want to have a distributor setup so you can increase the number of calls made to this service? Do you need a saga to do this?

Comment: Could you provide some kind of sequence for a call?  I'm having trouble understanding what is being scaled out.

Comment: Stephen - utilizing a Saga makes sense since the considered scenario is typical business workflow and it involves state transitions and depends on third party service interactions.

Comment: Adam - updated the question with a typical scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a number of design iterations we came up with the following guidelines,

1. Treat REST API layer as the integration platform.
2. Assume API endpoints are capable of abstracting fairly complex micro work-flows. Micro work-flows are operations that executes in a single burst (not interruptible) and completes with-in a short time span (<1 second).
3. Assume API farm is capable of serving many concurrent requests and can be easily scaled-out.
4. Favor synchronous invocations over asynchronous message based invocations when the target operation is fairly straightforward.
5. When asynchronous processing is required use a single message handler and invoke API from the handlers. This will delegate work to the API farm. This will also eliminate the need for a distributor and extra hardware resources.
6. Avoid Saga’s unless if the business work-flow contains multiple transactions, compensation logic and resumes. Tests reveals Sagas do not perform well under load.
7. Avoid consuming DomainServices directly from a message handler. This till do the work locally and also introduces a deployment hassle by distributing business logic.

Happy to hear out thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You are right on with identifying that you will need Sagas to manage workflow.  I'm willing to bet that your Domain hooks up to a common database.  If that is true then it will be faster to use your Domain directly and remove the serialization/network overhead.  You will also lose the ability to easily manage the transactions at the database level.

Assuming your are directly calling your Domain, the performance becomes a question of how the Domain performs.  You may take steps to optimize the database, drive down distributed transaction costs, sharding the data, etc.  You may end up using the Distributor to have multiple Saga processing nodes, but it sounds like you have some more testing to do once a design is chosen.

Generically speaking, we use REST APIs to model the commands as resources(via POST) to allow interaction with NSB from clients who don't have direct access to messaging.  This is a potential solution to get things onto NSB from your web app.